# Free abelian group, matrix representation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, free-groups, finitely-generated

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $A$ be a free abelian group and let $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ be a basis of $A$. Let $B$ be a subgroup generated by $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ and $M=(m_{ij})$ be a matrix over the integers such that $v_j=m_{1j}e_1+\dots+m_{nj}e_n$, $1\le j\le n$. (e.g, the columns are the $v_i$'s generating $B$.).

a. Prove $A/B$ is finite if and only if $\det M\ne 0$.

b. Assuming $A/B$ is finite, prove that $|A/B|=\det M$.

I basically need help with the second question. 
I would like, though, to know if my proof for a is valid:

proof:

a. (first direction) Assume $A/B$ is finite. Then $B$ is not {e}, for if it is, $A/B$ is isomorphic to $A$, and if $A$ is infinite, that would be a contradiction. I will prove by induction on n. For n=1: $B$ is not {e}(e=identity), and therefore $de_1$ is a basis of $B$ for an integer $d$. Therefore $\det M\ne 0$. Suppose now that if $A/B$ is finite, then $\det M\ne 0$, for $n$. I will show it is correct for $n+1$. (Here's where I am not so sure as for how valid what I am doing  is.). By my assumption, for $n$, if $A/B$ is finite, then $\det M\ne 0$, and therefore, $v_1,\dots,v_n$, represented by $e_1,\dots,e_n$, are linearly independent. Looking at the case $n+1$, we have $v_1,\dots,v_n$ linearly independent and represented by $e_1,\dots,e_n$ and we have $v_{n+1}$ represented by $e_1,\dots,e_{n+1}$. If $\det M=0$, then $v_{n+1}$ must be a linear combination of $v_1,\dots,v_n$. That is, $me_{n+1}$ is not in $B$ for every integer $m$. Therefore, there is infinite number of elements of the form $me_{n+1}$ that will create a new coset each, making a contradiction to the finiteness of $A/B$. The other direction is not that different…

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you, and sorry for the poor English, not my mother language.

Comment: Avoid `<`. It breaks things.

Comment: I'm trying to fix the math with MathJax; please, don't edit until I'm finished.

Comment: Oh I am sorry..

Comment: There were many mishaps and it went out not as I intended...

Comment: @Meitar I basically just changed $A\backslash B$ into the more usual $A/B$. For the rest I only fixed the math symbols adding the suitable markup.

Comment: Thank you, it looks so much better now.

Comment: Subgroups of groups can never be empty, because they must always contain the identity element, so the first couple of lines of your proof don't make much sense.

Comment: You can't assert that $d_ie_i$ is a basis of $B$. That won't work. For example, if $n=2$, you can take $B=\{ae_1+be_2\mid a+b\text{ is even}\}$. Then $B$ does not have a basis of the form $\{d_ie_i\}$.

Comment: I edited what I said about an empty group.

Comment: You still say $de_1$ is a basis for $B$, which is bizarre. @Meitar

Comment: Thomas, Why can't I assert it? I used first step of induction while the n I used is 1.Then the basis aforementioned is $e_1$. If B is a nontrivial subgroup then it is of the form $me_1$ making the number of cosets of B in A exactly m, which is the determinant, isn't that right? I'd like to know what's wrong in it...

Comment: @Meitar You never say induction, nor do you "Assume first $n=1$..." If you want an induction proof, you have to write an induction proof.

Comment: Oh my god I am so sorry. I didn't notice but half of what I have written just disappeared.. Those annoying bugs...

Comment: I edited it @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By fixing an identification, we may assume that $A = \mathbb{Z}^n.$ We can find two $n \times n$ invertible matrix $Q, P$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $QMP^{-1} =  diag(d_1, d_2, \cdots , d_r, 0, \cdots, 0), d_1|d_2| \cdots |d_r, r \leq n,$ with the property that there is a basis $y_1, y_2, \cdots , y_n$ such that $d_1y_1, d_2y_2, \cdots , d_ry_r$ is a basis of $B.$ So we change the basis of $A$ to $\{y_1, y_2, \cdots , y_n\}$ and we assume that $M$ is of the above mentioned form and $B$ is generated by $d_1y_1, d_2y_2, \cdots , d_ry_r.$ Now note that $detM \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow r=n \Leftrightarrow A/B$  $(\cong \mathbb{Z}/d_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}/d_n)$ is finite. This also gives the second result.

EDIT: $det (QMP^{-1}) = det Q. det M. det P^{-1} = \pm det M \Rightarrow det M = 0 \Leftrightarrow det (QMP^{-1}) = 0.$ Above we have proved that $det (QMP^{-1}) \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow A/B$ is finite. So $det M \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow A/B$ is finite. Using [Structure Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group) we can assume $M$ is a diagonal matrix and we do everything on that assumption. Going from $M$ to $QMP^{-1}$ we are basically giving automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ to change it's basis in a suitable form so that the matrix $M$ become a diagonal matrix.

The above procedure is not only true for free abelian groups of finite rank, it also true for any free modules of finite rank over a PID. In that case you need [Structure Theorem of Finitely Generated Modules over PID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain).

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any idea for the second part of the question?

Comment: @Meitar: with the above notations, $det M = d_1d_2 \cdots d_n.$ on the other hand $|A/B| = |\mathbb{Z}/d_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}/d_n| = d_1d_2 \cdots d_n.$

Comment: Isn't the determinant of the diagonal matrix a combination of |Q||M||P^-1|? I didn't quiet catch that one, or the part where you say they are of the same form... Can you repeat it, please? :)

Comment: Is Z/d1 the clock group of order d1? Just making sure... We just learned those theorems...

Comment: I will assume those are elementary matrices, thank you Krish! :)

Comment: @Meitar: $\mathbb{Z}/d_i$ is the cyclic group of order $d_i.$ And for (b), I think it means $|det M|.$ for example take the matrix associated to $v_1 = e_1, v_2 = -2e_2.$ In this case $det M = -2,$ and it can never be equal to $|A/B|$ since it is positive.

Comment: Yes that's how it was written originally.. I forgot to add it... That only question left is how you can be sure |Q||M||P^-1| equals to |M| equals to the determinant of the diagonal form...

Comment: @Meitar: $P$ is invertible means $det P = \pm 1.$ Smilarly for $Q.$ So $det (QMP^{-1}) = det Q. det M. det P^{-1} = \pm det M.$